# Should there be exactly one EFI partition?

Tags: uefi

My computer has two hard drives, both partitioned as GPT. The first one has Windows 10 installed and includes an EFI partition. Is there ever a reason to have more than one EFI partition, given that multiple OS's will be present?

Comment: You do not have to. And Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer only installs grub's UEFI boot files into whatever drive is seen as first drive, usually the Windows's drive's ESP. But you can have an ESP on other drives. I always partition in advance and include an ESP on every drive, even is just a data drive, for potential future use. Or if larger drive, I have a small Ubuntu install that can boot from that drive's ESP for emergency use. But also have multiple Flash drives for that also. Some like total separation. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Work aounds if desired.

Comment: When I first installed Ubuntu as a dual-boot, I set up an EFI partition on the new drive I was adding. The installer ignored it and used the existing one that was set up for Windows.

Comment: @organic-marble Yup, that's the bug 1396379.  Do add yourself to the bug's "Does this affect me?" list. Maybe It'll be fixed if enough people do that.  Note, running grub-install directly will install where you tell it to.  The advantage of another EFI grub is that then grub is not spread across two disks, and the system will boot with either (Windows on the first, grub on the second).

Comment: @ubfan1 did it long ago